# Excel count from external workbook with formula update excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm having problem with formula sync.
It only removes #value and adds number when the workbook is open.
I've added connections to the right file under DATA/edit links.

```
=COUNTA('R:\1008.xls]Page 1'!$G$2:$G$370)
```

Comment: This should not be so using `COUNTA`. Are you sure it is `COUNTA` and not one of those: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/260415/sumif--countif-and-countblank-functions-return-value-error is in calculation chain?

Comment: Sum(IF fixed the problem. thank you!